# Fish vi-mode bind Ctrl-o to quick command in insert mode

Tags: vi, key-bindings, fish

I'm new to fish shell and vim custom keybindings. I've put fish in vi-mode and I've noticed some commands were missing such as Ctrl-o in insert mode to execute a normal command. Does anyone know how to add this keybinding ?

I've successfully added the equivalent of:

`inoremap jk <ESC>`

with:

`bind -M insert jk 'set fish_bind_mode default; commandline -f repaint'`

But I have no idea how to wait for a command and go back to insert mode afterwards. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First of all:

> bind -M insert jk 'set fish_bind_mode default; commandline -f repaint'

Could also just be

```
bind -M insert -m default jk 'commandline -f repaint'
```

("-m" is short for "--sets-mode", I'm not sure why this doesn't repaint on its own)

---

Running one command in normal mode is tricky. Because you have to run code after one binding is executed, so you'll have to touch all the bindings.

One possibility is to create a new "default-one" mode, via

```
bind -M insert -m default-one \co 'commandline -f repaint'
```

and then you'll have to duplicate all bindings for "default" mode (see them via `bind -M default`) to add a `-m insert`. I'm not sure what to do with those things that already switch to a different mode like "v" (which switches to visual mode).

Comment: Sorry for commenting on it so lately. Your answer worked partially, 2 weeks ago, it sometimes screwed the current command until I hit Ctrl-c and retyped it. But today it seems to work great for some reason, so I select you as best answer.

Comment: I won't do the Ctrl-o trick tho, too tedious for the result, I don't like overly complicated configs. Thanks for sharing it still.